# How to perform UITesting on an app I don't have source code for?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I have been reading up on Apple's new and improved XCTest/UITesting frameworks and I have some questions as a Android developer. In android, to launch an app that I do not have the source code for to run UiAutomator I would simply use

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    //Init UiDevice instance
    Instrumentation mInstrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
    mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(mInstrumentation);

    //start from home screen on each new test
    mDevice.pressHome();

    //wait for launcher
    final String launcherPackage = mDevice.getLauncherPackageName();
    assertThat(launcherPackage, notNullValue());
    mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(launcherPackage).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);

    //launch app
    Context mContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    final Intent intent = mContext.getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(GMAIL_APP_PACKAGE);

    //Clear any previous instances
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);

    //wait for app to appear
    mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(GMAIL_APP_PACKAGE).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
    mDevice.waitForWindowUpdate(null, 5000);
}
```

Using the above code, i am able to launch the package i want then use UiAutomatorView.bat to inspect the elements and get their resource id's (or find by text) then perform operations on them.

In iOS, all of the tutorials that i've found centre on testing apps that you have access to source code for. While I understand that it is much simpler to write these tests in iOS since you simply record the actions you wish to perform and xcode writes the code for you, I am unsure as to how to set the UI Test Target to an app that is currently installed on my device. I watched the WWDC video that went over multi-app testing using this:

```
var gmailApp: XCUIApplication!
gmailApp.launchArguments = "-StartFromCleanState", "YES"]
gmailApp.launch()
```

however this will not work since it has no target.

TL;DR: How do I set an app installed on my device, such as gmail, as my UI Test Target, and how do i discover package names in order to launch the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, I hope that this isn't the case. I know that it's possible to use this method to access the Settings app or Safari, so I hope it would be able to be used for 3rd party apps as well.

Comment: For security purposes, each app is placed in a sandbox at install time to restrict access to only the applications own files, with the exception of certain device files and sensors which can be accessed by the application requesting explicit permission from the user to do so. It is not possible for one application to access another in the manner you are seeking. See this for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html

Comment: More on why: "If malicious code gains control of a properly sandboxed app, it is left with access to only the files and resources in the app’s sandbox." Additionally, the application publisher (such as Google) would likely not want you to have that ability either.

Comment: The link above is specific to macOS sandboxing but the same concepts apply.

Comment: It is possible. As mfeltmann mentioned, you need to pass only Bundle Identifier. https://super-tester.medium.com/ios-how-to-automate-tests-for-apps-without-having-access-to-development-source-code-a35824abd5e3

Answer (score 1):

You only need the bundle identifier to launch another application.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/2879415-initwithbundleidentifier?language=objc

I use this for macOS testing a lot so I guess it will work for iOS as well.

Comment: Is it possible without sourcecode, I mean, lets say the app is in an iPhone and I want to Automate the app directly from the device (assuming that i know bundle Identifer)

Comment: Yes it's possible